# Use the Fitch System to prove (p ⇒ (q ⇒ r)) ⇒ ((p ⇒ q) ⇒ (p ⇒ r)).

Tags: propositional-calculus

It's really complex and I really need a simple way to do it. I just go blank when I see it. Please help...

Comment: Do you understand what the "Fitch system" is?

Comment: (for others: [Fitch notation on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation))

Comment: Build the truth table, then convert that into a "Fitch system" proof. This method is so simple, you can teach your computer to do it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table.

Answer (score 2):

As a general strategy: if you ever need to prove a conditional, start a subproof where you assume the 'if' part, and try to get to the 'then' part as your last line of the subproof, after which you can close the subproof and infer the conditional using $\rightarrow \ Intro$

Here is a proof made in 'Fitch', a software program to make Fitch proofs:

[image]

Comment: You made three hypotheses.  If you have proof by contradiction {$\lnot$x ... {y, $\lnot$y}} $\vdash$ x, and the rules $\lnot$(x -> y) $\vdash$ x, $\lnot$(x -> y) $\vdash$ $\lnot$ y, it could get proved with a single hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

The key is this: in order to prove a statement of the form $A \implies B$, begin by assuming $A$ and try to conclude that $B$ is true using *any* previous assumptions.  Here's how we can do this proof:

```
[Want to prove: (p->(q->r))->(p->q)->(p->r)]
1. Assume: (p->(q->r))
    [Want to prove: (p->q)->(p->r)]
    2. Assume: (p->q)
        [Want to prove: p->r]
        3. Assume p
            [Want to prove: r]
            4. By 2, we can conclude that q is also true
            5. By 1, we can conclude that q->r.
            6. Because q and (q->r), conclude that r is true
            [By proving r with assumption p, we have proven that p->r]
        7. Thus, p->r
        [By proving (p->r) with assumption (p-> q), we have proven that (p->q)->(p->r)]
    8. Thus, (p->q)->(p->r)
    [we have now proven that (p->(q->r))->(p->q)->(p->r), as desired]
```